# Предложения 1.1. и 1.2. / Предложения 1.1 и 1.2

Tags: орфография

Как мне лучше ответить на то, какие предложения правильны? То есть нужна точка?

1.1. Я попробовал рыбу карася, которую папа купил, на зубок, так чтобы, если она окажется невкусной, я её не выплюнул. Она была прел-л-л-лестной!

1.2. Я попробовал рыбу карася, которую папа купил, назубок, так чтобы, если она окажется невкусной, я её не выплюнул. Она была прел-л-л-лестной!

2.1. Я теперь правила о — ё — е после шипящих на зубок знаю, хотя однажды, два года назад, я написал жолудь.

2.2. Я теперь правила о — ё — е после шипящих назубок знаю, хотя однажды, два года назад, я написал жолудь.

> Предложения 1.1. и 1.2. правильны.

> Предложения 1.1 и 1.2 правильны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Верно с точкой:

*Предложения **1.1.** и **1.2.** правильны*.

**[Грамота](http://classic2.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281246)**:

> Нужна ли точка после последней цифры в нумерации рубрики, например: "1.1.1 Бумага"
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Да, точка нужна.